# How to fill and export simple JasperReports report as PDF file

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I'm newbie in JasperReports.

I'm trying to fill a simple JasperReport wtih an only parameter, and then export it as a PDF file. But **the PDF file is exported empty**.

I used Jaspersoft Studio to design the report. I got the following "invoice.jrxml" file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="invoice" pageWidth="612" pageHeight="1008" columnWidth="572" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="a9cee65a-1403-4afb-8df2-37033b911d04">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <parameter name="name" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="35" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="80" height="20" uuid="d762d314-715a-48d9-a3a0-5c147a6754a5"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="14"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Name:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="80" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="a396777c-6516-4b37-ad86-501b21c090f5"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="14"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{name}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </pageHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="125" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

(I tested in  Jasper Studio Preview tab, and it was worting fine.)

The report was compiled and I got a "invoice.jasper" file. I put this file in the classpath of my Java project.

Here is the code I try to fill the report and export it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JRException {
    JasperReport reporte = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(new File("invoice.jasper"));

    Map<String, Object> parametros = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    parametros.put("name", "Adrián");

    JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reporte, parametros);

    JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, "invoice.pdf");
}
```

I can't understand why the report is blank.

Comment: `I can't understand why the report is blank.` - You did not pass datasource

Answer (score 0):

Adrian, try the following:

```
    ClassLoader classloader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    InputStream inputStream = classloader.getResourceAsStream(fileName);
    JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(inputStream);
    Map<String, Object> parametros = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    parametros.put("name", "Adrián");
    JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parametros);
    JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, "invoice.pdf");
```

This code receive a `fileName`, this fileName should be your **.jrxml** file. The code will receive the source code for the report, and compile it at run time.

Comment: The .jrxml file don't compile at run time: Exception in thread "main" net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: java.net.MalformedURLException

Comment: The jrxml file compile in Jaspersoft Studio!

Comment: It can be compiled at your runtime...I took it from a code I made in other project :) checkout how you are forming your path

Comment: I found the problem. Now I fill the report with "JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reporte, parametros, new JREmptyDataSource());". (I added the last parameter to the fillReport() method.)